# Can't configure Bluetooth on 16.04 Server

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, bluez

I have been trying to follow multiple tutorials, but all of them either reference `hidd` or `bluez-simple-agent`.
I have installed `bluez` `bluez-tools` `bluetooth`, but when I run `hidd` or `bluez-simple-agent` I get `command not found`.

I have tried to:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bluez bluez-tools bluetooth && sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-tools bluetooth
```

But that yields the same results.

My end goal is to pair a bluetooth keyboard. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/707587/543928) AskUbuntu post using `bluetoothctl`. If you can't type in the `bluetoothctl` prompt, run it with `sudo`.

I also ran `[bluetooth]# trust [keyboard MAC Address]`