# Bluetooth keyboard problem

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I can't get bluetooth keyboards to connect in Ubuntu 16.04.
A bluetooth mouse connects fine without issue.
I have tried 3 different dongles and two different keyboards. One keyboard is a standard bluetooth keyboard and the other (which I'm keen to get to work) is a Recreated Spectrum - which is pretty much a standard bluetooth keyboard.
The dongles and keyboards all work fine on my Windows machine.
I've tried the different PIN setting with no joy.
They show up OK but when I try to connect they eventual come up with 'failed'.
Tried "sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 0" and it tells me "Can't set Simple Pairing mode on hci0: Input/Output error (5)"

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work through the command line based on this [Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/707587) and this [Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323968#post_13487621).

First unplug the bluetooth dongle and delete configuration files:

```
sudo \rm -rf /var/lib/bluetooth/*
```

Then replug the bluetooth dongle and run `bluetoothctl`. In the `bluetoothctl` prompt, type the following commands:

```
power on
agent on
default-agent 
scan on
```

Turn on the bluetooth keyboard in discovery mode. Soon `bluetoothctl` will print the keyboard device ID in the format `FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA`. Then proceed with pairing:

```
pair FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA
```

It will request a PIN code, type that code in the keyboard and hit enter. You will get a success message. Then finalize the configuration:

```
trust FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA
connect FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA
```

The keyboard should now work.

Comment: Thanks! Well.. it half worked. My "Logik" keyboard seems to be working fine however my "Recreated ZX Spectrum", no chance. All I get when trying to pair is "Authorization cancelled" after typing the PIN and waiting a few seconds. Looks like a Windows win for the Recreated ZX Spectrum!

Comment: Thanks! your approach is only one worked for me: Ubuntu 16.04, MX Master Logitech mouse

Comment: Thank you. Worked for me on Linux Mint 21.2. Instead of unplugging the bluetooth dongle (which is internal to my laptop), I made a "power off" in the beginning.