# How to set up device at Ubuntu 18.04 Bluetooth Settings?

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I am at `Settings > Bluetooth`. I turned Bluetooth on in order to send a file to my phone and my ZTE Axon7 is listed under "Devices" as "Not set up". When I click on it, the rotating orange circle seems to indicate that it's trying something, but it soon returns to "Not set up".

```
$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 2C:33:7A:F2:00:F6 AWESOME-O [default]
[NEW] Device 18:68:6A:EE:7B:B9 ZTE AXON7
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# pair 18:68:6A:EE:7B:B9
Attempting to pair with 18:68:6A:EE:7B:B9
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed
[bluetooth]#
```

I had entered "scan on", and "discoverable on" beforehand ([as outlined in this Ubuntu Forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2338474])), but it doesn't seem to be necessary. I have also [installed the latest version of TLP](https://askubuntu.com/a/927987/392746).

How can I connect my phone to my laptop in order to exchange files?

Comment: Suggestion: Ensure that the agent is registered as per [this older answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/707587/37165). In terminal `[bluetooth]#`, run first `agent on`, `default-agent`, then only the pairing command.

Comment: Try removing the device from Bluetooth settings, close settings. Then open settings and add your device

Answer (score 2):

I had a lot of problems with bluetooth, and navigating the array of settings was problematic. I found that blueman was a really handy interface for setting up devices.

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
blueman-manager
```

And try pairing and connecting the devices through this tool?

I found that this tool displayed an error message when pairing a device that I hadn't managed to surface through other approaches.

Comment: Indeed, blueman-manager is *the* solutiion, all problems gone... Lost so much time with the default Ubuntu bluetooth handler :(